# android - loop through dynamically added form inputs

Tags: android, android-edittext, spinner

I have dynamically added edittexts and spinners into my activity. What is the best way to iterate through all of the dynamically added inputs to validate and get their text values?

Should i create and add to a hashmap with the inputs' id's as the key and and string element type(eddittext, spinner) and then iterate through that or is there a more standard way of doing this?

Comment: I think you're answering your own question. If you're dynamically adding the widgets, you might as well keep track of them in a HashMap, which will give you direct access to each widget. Otherwise you could use `getChildAt()` and `getChildCount()` to walk the ViewGroups.

Comment: what do you mean by direct access? if i put the id and type(a string value) in a hashmap it wouldn't give me "direct" access. i'd use it for reference

Comment: Create your HashMap as `HashMap<Integer, View>` and you have direct access. Just be sure to free in `onDestroy` or you'll leak memory. To avoid that, you could use a `HashMap<Integer, WeakReference<View>>`. Obviously, in either case, the Integer would be the id. If that doesn't tell you what type it is, you could always use `instanceof` to check.

Comment: If you want a bit more of an answer, post the code which creates your Activity, and I'll edit it.